# Proof verification of $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-1} x^2 = 1$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, proof-verification

$\displaystyle\lim_{x\to-1} x^2 = 1$

Let $\epsilon>0$

$|x^2-1|=|x-1||x+1|$

Since $x\to-1$, we can assume $|x+1|<1$, then:

$-1<x+1<1$

$-3<x-1<-1<3$

$|x-1|<3$

Then $|x²-1|=|x-1||x+1|<3|x+1|$

Let $ \delta = \min(1,\frac{\epsilon}{3})$

Then $|x+1|<\delta \Rightarrow |x²-1|<3\frac{\epsilon}{3}=\epsilon$

$\square$

What makes me uncertain is this part:
$-3<x-1<-1<3 \Rightarrow |x-1|<3$

I can't see any problem with it, but this website http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/CalcI/DefnOfLimit.aspx
when proving a similar limit, $\displaystyle \lim_{x\to4} x^2+x-11=9$, says that "(the positive part is important here)", while I didn't find a positive value on the left side of my inequality. Why does it need to be positive? Is my proof incorrect then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In that website, he just want to make sure that $x + 5 = |x + 5|$ so the positive part is important. That is, $8 < x + 5 < 10$ hence $8 < |x + 5| < 10$ and then just take $|x + 5| < 10$ part, and yes your answer is correct.

Answer (score 0):

You do have found a "positive part" of the limit, which is $3$. The philosophy is that, do not let $x$ vary too far away from $-1$ (as you have controlled by $|x+1|<1$), so the distance for all such $x$ with another points (in this case, $1$) is not too large, so eventually $|x+1||x-1|$ can be controlled by a multiple of $|x+1|$.

Answer (score 0):

Well, since $x$ approaches $-1$, the distance between $1$ and $-1$ approaches $2$, and with your delta, $x$ will be at most $3$ from $1$ (no farther away than $-2$), so your bound on $|x-1|$ looks perfectly reasonable to me!